# проблема с border при масштабировании

Tags: html, css, float, border

В контейнере с `width:100px` несколько блоков со свойствами `float:left; border:1px solid black;width:23px;` при 100% масштаба видим 4 блока в ряд, но как только масштабируем блоки съезжают, и их становится 3 в ряд, почему? Как я понял проблема в border, но как ее избежать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте для блоков с бордерами задать `box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Для Firefox */` и `width:25px`

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.wrapper{
 width:100px;
 margin:20px auto;
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
.wrapper:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
.wrapper div{
 float:left;
 width:25%;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid red;
}
.wrapper div:first-child{
 background:blue;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2){
  background:lightblue;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(3){
  background:green;
}
.wrapper div:last-child{
  background:lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <div class=""></div>
   <div class=""></div>
   <div class=""></div>
   <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

Вот смотрите , выше ответ и мой указывают на `box-sizing:border-box;`и блоки при фиксированном размере не может съужаться